# Number of open file descriptors won't change when I set them in CentOS 6.3?

Tags: linux, centos, open-files

```
uname -a
Linux lab.testing.com 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 03:33:56 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

ulimit -Hn
1024

ulimit -Sn
1024

ulimit -n
1024
```

I opened `/etc/sysctl.conf` in `vi` and added this at the bottom:

```
fs.file-max = 65536
```

I opened `/etc/security/limits.conf` in `vi` and added this at the bottom:

```
*        soft    open files      8192

*        hard    open files     10240

testuser   soft    open files      8192

testuser   hard    open files     10240
```

Whether I login as `root` or as `testuser`, and whether I reboot or cold-boot the box, I still get:

```
ulimit -Hn
1024

ulimit -Sn
1024

ulimit -n
1024
```

I can set the open file descriptors to 10240 at the command line but that only sets it for the session and then it's lost when I logout/login and/or reboot/cold-boot:

[root@lab ~]# ulimit -n 10240

```
[root@lab ~]# ulimit -Hn   
10240

[root@lab ~]# ulimit -Sn   
10240

[root@lab ~]# ulimit -n    
10240
```

What am I missing?

And in case someone wants to see the initial values:

```
[root@itnm ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 46464
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 46464
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misconfigure the limits.conf file. There is no option like open files.

```
 - **nofile** - max number of open file descriptors
```

You should be using "nofile" option instead of open files. That will solve the problem i think.

Comment: Erdem: that resolved it.  I guess I misunderstood the option to pass when I read through the options in the file.  My sincerest thanks for your help.  This has been a problem for me for a long time.